# File server home share not available

Tags: linux, centos, samba, centos-7, file-server

I have configured a file server on CentOS 7 to share home directories using this guide, [Setup file server on CentOS 7 – Step by Step](http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-file-server-centos-7/). But it's showing blank window when I'm trying to access share. I could see the service is up and running fine.

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status smb
● smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smb.service; disabled; vendor     preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-06-12 16:34:15 IST; 7min ago
Main PID: 3251 (smbd)
Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
CGroup: /system.slice/smb.service
       ├─3251 /usr/sbin/smbd
       ├─3252 /usr/sbin/smbd
       ├─3253 /usr/sbin/smbd
       └─3254 /usr/sbin/smbd

 Jun 12 16:34:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Jun 12 16:34:15 localhost.localdomain smbd[3251]: [2017/06/12 16:34:15.45648...
Jun 12 16:34:15 localhost.localdomain smbd[3251]:   STATUS=daemon 'smbd' fin...
Jun 12 16:34:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Samba SMB Daemon.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Home block in `smb.conf`:

```
[homes]
  comment = Home Directories
  browseable = No
  inherit acls = Yes
  read only = No
  valid users = %S %D%w%S
```

Firewall is turned off and SELinux is enabled and `home dir allowed`. Am I missing anything ?